# Publish Failing because of file location

Tags: .net-core, single-page-application, angular9

I am trying to publish a .Net Core 3.1 application using the command:

```
dotnet publish -r win10-x86 -c Release --self-contained=True
```

While running it calls the command `npm run build --prod` which builds the angular application and copies the compiled files to the `wwwroot` folder in `aspnetcore`.

while running it gets to some of the assets and fails because they are in an assets folder

I can run `ng build --prod` successfully.

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(237,5):
> error MSB3030: Could not copy the file
> "C:\Users\Some Path\wwwroot\some file name.eot"
> because it was not found.
> [C:\Users\some full path.csproj]

Which this should be looking in `C:\Users\Some Path\wwwroot\assets\some file name.eot`

my `csproj` file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
      <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
      <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
      <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
      <SpaRoot>UI\</SpaRoot>

      <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
      <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
    <!-- <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'"> -->
    <!--     <PostBuildEvent>npm run production</PostBuildEvent> -->
    <!-- </PropertyGroup> -->

  <ItemGroup>
      <Content Remove="$(UI)**" />
      <None Remove="$(UI)**" />
      <None Include="$(UI)**" Exclude="$(UI)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Collections" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.Debug" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Extensions" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Handles" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\some project.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\some project.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\some project.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
        <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
        <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
            <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
        </Exec>
        <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
        <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

        <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
            <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
            <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
                <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
                <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
                <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
            </ResolvedFileToPublish>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Exec Command="npm run production" />
  </Target>


</Project>
```

So on to my question, where do I change this to look in the correct folder for these assets?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. the issue was this:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
```

should be

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build --prod" />
```